# How to enable the automatic line breaks in LaTeX and forced the text to break?

Tags: tables, tabularx, cell

I have created a table, and I have fixed its width, but the problem when I write a long text, the text breaks the line, I want to add an automatic line break  when the text should respect the width of the line. how can I do that ?
I used template of springer.
This is my table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}



        \begin{table*}[htp]
        \scriptsize     
        
        %\begin{tabular}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        
        
        \begin{tabular} {|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.01\textwidth}|} 
        \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
        Type of ANN\end{tabular} 
        
        &
        
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x \end{tabular} 
        &
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x \end{tabular} 
        
        & Topology & 
        
        Input & Output & Objective & Dataset & Ref \\ \hline
        {\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox [origin=c]{90}{x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x }}}  & { \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox [origin=c]{90}{ Regression }}} & \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & 
        
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        \tabitem x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\\
        \tabitem x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  .\\
        \tabitem x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .
        \\
        
        
        \end{tabular}
        
        
         & 
        
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\\
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  \\   
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  \\ %\hspace{0.28cm}
         rate.
        \\
        
        
          & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & r1 \\ \cline{3-9} 
         &  & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & 
         
         
         
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  \\
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  \\
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  \\
        
        
          & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x   model.\end{tabular} & r2 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-9} 
        {\rotatebox [origin=c]{90}{ Feedback }}  &  & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & 
        
         \begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}
        Number of  users  connected in $t_{n}$.
        \\
        \end{tabular}
        
         & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  $t_{n+1}$.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{//} & r3 \\ \hline
        {\rotatebox [origin=c]{90}{   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x    }} & {\rotatebox [origin=c]{90}{ Classification }} & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}One hidden  layer.\end{tabular} & 
        
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  . \\
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . \\ 
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . \\
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . \\
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . \\
         x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . \\
        
         & \begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x .\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x \end{tabular} & r4 \\ \hline
        
        \end{tabular}
        
        \end{table*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference to your previous (aparently now deleted) question? Did you already try to incorporate the suggestions that were made in the comments there?

Comment: @leandriis I think the people did not understand me in the previous question, my question is that how to able the automatic line breaks.

Comment: The automatic linebreaks do not work in your table because of all the nested tabulars in most of the cells (`\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}`)  and because LaTeX does not know where to add a linebreak inside of something like `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `.

Comment: What kind of contents does your actual table contain? I assume `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ` is just some kind of placeholder or does your table actually contain `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `? As I already commented on your previous question: Please make an example that contains contents closer to your actual table.

Comment: The xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx are a simple text, just words.

Comment: If you do not want to reveal the actual contents of your table, which I can totally understand, you could use something like `this is some placeholder text` instead of `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549104/divide-table-line-by-two-rather-than-resizing-table

Comment: @leandriis thank you very much I remove all the tabular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know the desired layout as the posted code generated too many errors to make any output, and you did not supply an image of the required layout.

But perhaps this can get you started, I removed all the inner tabular that were preventing line breaking (as they were forcing `l` columns) and adjusted the outer table to fit what appears to be your 7 main column headings. All the columns allow line breaking, but in practice you will want to adjust the widths depending on the real meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}



\begin{table*}[htp]
\scriptsize     
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        
\begin{tabular} {@{}|
p{0.15\textwidth}|
p{0.15\textwidth}|
p{0.15\textwidth}|
p{0.1\textwidth}|
p{0.1\textwidth}|
p{0.1\textwidth}|
p{0.1\textwidth}|
@{}} 
        \hline

        Type of ANN
        
         & Topology & 
        
        Input & Output & Objective & Dataset & Ref \\ \hline


x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x &
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x x x x x x x x x x  \\
        


zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz & 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz & 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz &
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz & 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz & 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz & 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz  \\
\hline        
\end{tabular}
        
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

[image]